# In NGINX error occured like redirected you too many times for rewrite to mobile

Tags: nginx

I want to set different URLs for desktop and mobile
I already tried this code in nginx.conf file

```
http {
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  1.2.3.4;

    set $mobile_request false;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* '(Mobile|WebOS)') {
      set $mobile_request true;
  }

  if ($mobile_request = true) {
      rewrite ^ /high-mobile/html;   #path of my mobile html files
      break;
  }

  if ($mobile_request = false) {
      rewrite ^ /high/html;   #path of my desktop html files
      break;
  }

  location / {
      root   /home/ubuntuvm/;   #root url
      index  index.html index.htm;     #default home page
  }
```

This is my code when i hit the url in  browser it gave error like

redirected you too many times

***Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
http://1.2.3.4/high-mobile/html/#/:1 GET http://1.2.3.4/high-mobile/html/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS***

Thankyou in advance.....

Comment: Maybe the rule redirects to itself?

Comment: What happens if you add `permanent` like `rewrite ^ /high-mobile/html permanent;`

Comment: @Hackerman i tried but didn't working

Comment: @Hackerman is right. This is redirecting to itself. After you perform the rewrite, it re-enters the server block. But it will always fall into either `if` statement, and so the redirect loop occurs. I'll attempt an answer below. If it fails, please tell me what the outcome is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a solution.

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  1.2.3.4;

        set $mobile_request false;

        #If it's a mobile user-agent, set it to true.
        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(Mobile|WebOS)') {
            set $mobile_request true;
        }

        #If it's not a request to a mobile site, append "desktop" to the "mobile_request" variable.
        if ($request_uri !~ "^.*/high-mobile/.*$"){
            set $mobile_request "${mobile_request}+desktop";
        }

        #If it is a mobile user-agent AND it is a request to the desktop site, redirect to the mobile site. 
        if ($mobile_request = "true+mobile") {

            #Clear the variable of any data, so that it doesn't induce a redirect loop with old data for new requests.
            set $mobile_request "";

            rewrite ^ /high-mobile/html;   #path of my mobile html files
            break;
        }

        location / {
            root   /home/ubuntuvm/;   #root url
            index  index.html index.htm;     #default home page
        }
    }
}
```

The assumption made in the solution:

All requests are by default to the desktop site and `/high/` is in the URI, thus there is no need to check the negation of `$mobile_request`.

If this is not the case, you'll need to post your full NGINX configuration as well as the directory structure you're using. Any config more complicated than this is generally wrong unless you're trying to do something very specific or you're supporting a legacy infrastructure. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution

```
location = /high/ {
if ($mobile_request = true) {
      return 301 $scheme://ip_addr/high-mobile/html/index.html#/;
    }
```

Comment: @gabber-vicksy You can accept your answer 2 days after posting it.